# NoClassDefFoundError Singletonholder

Tags: java, singleton, noclassdeffounderror, vaadin7

Good day everyone! I have recently deployed a web project and I am getting a NoClassDefFoundError when trying to get an instance of a singleton class.

> com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager$RpcInvocationException: Unable to invoke method click in
>   com.vaadin.shared.ui.button.ButtonServerRpc   at
>   com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:170)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:287)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:180)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler$3.run(PushHandler.java:174)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler.callWithUi(PushHandler.java:253)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler.access$200(PushHandler.java:56)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler$1.onRequest(PushHandler.java:76)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:174)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.container.GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport.service(GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport.java:60)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:1802)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.dispatch(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:432)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor$2.run(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:285)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.util.VoidExecutorService.execute(VoidExecutorService.java:101)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.dispatch(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:280)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.invokeWebSocketProtocol(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:303)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.container.GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport$Grizzly2WebSocketApplication.onMessage(GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport.java:157)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.SimpleWebSocket.onMessage(SimpleWebSocket.java:163)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.frametypes.TextFrameType.respond(TextFrameType.java:68)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.DataFrame.respond(DataFrame.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.BaseWebSocketFilter.handleRead(BaseWebSocketFilter.java:219)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:168)
>     ... 35 more Caused by:
>   com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException: Invocation of method
>   buttonClick in
>   no.solarsoft.venus2.admissionweb2.presentation.components.wizard.contentparts.PaymentPanel$2
>   failed.   at
>   com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:528)
>     at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)     at
>   com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)  at
>   com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:979)
>     at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:393)  at
>   com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)  ... 40 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError     at
>   no.solarsoft.venus2.payex.wsclient.PxOrderManager.getInstance(PxOrderManager.java:54)
>     at
>   no.solarsoft.venus2.admissionweb2.payment.payex.AbstractPayExHelper.initializeOrder(AbstractPayExHelper.java:60)
>     at
>   no.solarsoft.venus2.admissionweb2.payment.payex.PayExCreditCardHelper.initializeOrder(PayExCreditCardHelper.java:60)
>     at
>   no.solarsoft.venus2.admissionweb2.presentation.view.ApplicationWizardView$PaymentPanelModelPropertyChangeListener.propertyChange(ApplicationWizardView.java:1599)
>     at
>   java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
>     at
>   java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
>     at
>   no.solarsoft.venus2.admissionweb2.presentation.components.wizard.content.model.PaymentPanelModel.createCreditCardPaymentEvent(PaymentPanelModel.java:210)
>     at
>   no.solarsoft.venus2.admissionweb2.presentation.components.wizard.contentparts.PaymentPanel$2.buttonClick(PaymentPanel.java:272)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
>     ... 45 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: MASM0001:
>   Default configuration file [ jaxws-tubes-default.xml ] was not found
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.MetroConfigLoader.init(MetroConfigLoader.java:142)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.MetroConfigLoader.(MetroConfigLoader.java:119)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController.getTubeCreators(TubelineAssemblyController.java:93)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.MetroTubelineAssembler.createClient(MetroTubelineAssembler.java:118)
>     at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.createPipeline(Stub.java:343)     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.(Stub.java:310)  at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.(Stub.java:243)  at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.(Stub.java:258)  at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.(SEIStub.java:98)     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getStubHandler(WSServiceDelegate.java:829)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:818)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:451)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:419)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:401)
>     at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:134)   at
>   com.payex.external.pxorder.PxOrder.getPxOrderSoap(PxOrder.java:83)    at
>   no.solarsoft.venus2.payex.wsclient.PxOrderManager.init(PxOrderManager.java:60)
>     at
>   no.solarsoft.venus2.payex.wsclient.PxOrderManager.(PxOrderManager.java:46)
>     at
>   no.solarsoft.venus2.payex.wsclient.PxOrderManager.(PxOrderManager.java:45)
>     at
>   no.solarsoft.venus2.payex.wsclient.PxOrderManager$PxOrderManagerSingletonHolder.(PxOrderManager.java:50)
>     ... 58 more]]
>
> ```
> [2015-09-05T09:30:09.061+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid:
> _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1441438209061] [levelValue: 1000] [[
> ```
>
> no.solarsoft.venus2.admissionweb2.CustomNavigator$InitializationException:
>   ViewInitializer could not be found for view named "stdError".     at
>   no.solarsoft.venus2.admissionweb2.CustomNavigator.initView(CustomNavigator.java:91)
>     at
>   no.solarsoft.venus2.admissionweb2.CustomNavigator.navigateTo(CustomNavigator.java:123)
>     at
>   no.solarsoft.venus2.admissionweb2.AdmissionWebUI$1.error(AdmissionWebUI.java:211)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.LegacyCommunicationManager.handleConnectorRelatedException(LegacyCommunicationManager.java:397)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:290)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:180)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler$3.run(PushHandler.java:174)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler.callWithUi(PushHandler.java:253)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler.access$200(PushHandler.java:56)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler$1.onRequest(PushHandler.java:76)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:174)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.container.GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport.service(GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport.java:60)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:1802)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.dispatch(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:432)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor$2.run(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:285)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.util.VoidExecutorService.execute(VoidExecutorService.java:101)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.dispatch(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:280)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.invokeWebSocketProtocol(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:303)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.container.GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport$Grizzly2WebSocketApplication.onMessage(GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport.java:157)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.SimpleWebSocket.onMessage(SimpleWebSocket.java:163)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.frametypes.TextFrameType.respond(TextFrameType.java:68)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.DataFrame.respond(DataFrame.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.BaseWebSocketFilter.handleRead(BaseWebSocketFilter.java:219)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)]]

Here is the code of my PxOrderManager:

```
package no.solarsoft.venus2.payex.wsclient;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import no.solarsoft.venus2.admissionweb2.AdmissionWebUI;
import no.solarsoft.venus2.admissionweb2.AdmissionWebUI.RuntimeMode;

import com.payex.external.pxorder.PxOrder;
import com.payex.external.pxorder.PxOrderSoap;

public class PxOrderManager {

    private static final QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://external.payex.com/PxOrder/", "PxOrder");
    private static final String TEST_WSDL_LOCATION_STRING = "https://test-external.payex.com/pxorder/pxorder.asmx?WSDL";
    private static final String WSDL_LOCATION_STRING = "https://external.payex.com/pxorder/pxorder.asmx?WSDL";
    private static final URL WSDL_LOCATION;

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(PxOrderManager.class);

    // This initializes WSDL location. !!! USE TEST_WSDL_LOCATION_STRING for
    // testing against test web services.
    static {
        URL url = null;
        String urlString = null;
        try {
            urlString = AdmissionWebUI.RUNTIME_MODE.equals(RuntimeMode.PRODUCTION) ? WSDL_LOCATION_STRING
                    : TEST_WSDL_LOCATION_STRING;
            url = new URL(urlString);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PxOrder.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO,
                    "Can not initialize the default wsdl from {0}", urlString);
        }
        WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

    private PxOrder service;
    private PxOrderSoap port;

    private PxOrderManager() {
        init(WSDL_LOCATION);
    }

    private static class PxOrderManagerSingletonHolder {
        public static final PxOrderManager INSTANCE = new PxOrderManager();
    }

    public static PxOrderManager getInstance() {
        return PxOrderManagerSingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private void init(URL wsdlUrl) {
        log.info("Initializing web service with wsdl location at: " + wsdlUrl.toString());
        service = new PxOrder(wsdlUrl, SERVICE_NAME);
        port = service.getPxOrderSoap();
    }

    public PxOrderSoap getPort() {
        return this.port;
    }
}
```

I have tried to check the contents of my `war` file and it appears normal. The classes `PxOrderManagerSingletonHolder` and `PxOrderManager` exists

[image]

All of my `jar` files are in `web-inf/lib` folder. I am using vaadin 7 and jdk 1.6.0_45 (if it helps)

I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in different place (not `NoClassDefFoundError`). In your stacktrace is such information:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: MASM0001: Default configuration file [ jaxws-tubes-default.xml ] was not found

The solution is described [here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26795466/5162026).

Edit:

Moreover it would be great to consider Java version upgrade. [Vaadin Book](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/getting-started.environment.html) says:

> Vaadin is compatible with Java 1.6 and later editions. Java EE 7 is required for proper server push support with WebSockets.

Comment: thanks! I just found out that the problem is in different place. there was this atmosphere and push thingy that destroys the code.